# node.js - why anonymous callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I'm learning node.js, and have noticed that pretty much all callbacks are inlined as anonymous callbacks into the function. Is there a specific reason behind doing things this way?

I think using a named callback, and defining it as a local function has 2 advantages:
1. it's cleaner, and doesn't turn the function into one giant block of code
2. given an appropriate name, it acts as documentation - describing what the callback is supposed to do

Comment: This sort of polling discussion question is better suited for [chat] ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using named functions in the global scope as callbacks, the scope where the function is named may cause the function to persist in memory and prevents it from being garbage collected. This is one of the many ways to cause memory leaks in your application. Anonymous functions on the other hand, are marked for GC immediately after their execution is over, and anything not returned (could be a closure as well) will be auto marked for garbage collection.

Consider a fairly complex jQuery plugin. Before generating and returning the actual object that is the subject of the plugin, it may have to create dozens of variables that hold temporary state data. If this were not done in an IIFE (Immediately invoked function expression: an anonymous function that is immediately executed), these variable would "leak" into the global scope. Data in JavaScript will remain in memory as long as there is any one variable or closure still referencing it. Since these variables have "leaked" to the global scope, they will remain in memory until that tab/window is closed. When defined inside an IIFE, the variables defined are stuck in the local anonymous function's scope. Thus, when the function has completed execution, the variables are "gone" and their data no longer has any references. The JS Engine's garbage collector notices that this specific data in memory is not being referenced anywhere anymore, and marks it for deletion, freeing up the occupied memory for other data.

So if you named your functions and you're calling them only once, it's possible they are needlessly taking up memory. Making them anonymous will reclaim the memory after execution, reducing your app's memory overhead.

This is essentially a description of how most dynamic languages work, and why they are more popular than static languages like C, where you have to keep track of every memory allocation you've made, and make sure you delete them when you no longer need them (an exercise in itself; deciding how long you'll need a particular data is not trivial always).

Comment: Is this a quirk of a particular implementation or general behavior? If the latter, can you provide a source or a concrete example?

Comment: It's a fundamental feature/issue of garbage collected dynamic languages. It's not just javascript, several other languages support anonymous functions (Scala, Haskell, Ruby's lambda blocks, etc). I'll expand this answer to include an example of a generic jquery module, since it is easier to visualize than a nodejs module.

Comment: Before, I thought you were claiming that code like `(function() { function myCallback() { alert('callbacked'); } doSomething(myCallback); })();` was leaky due to its use of a named function, but your edit seems to focus on the presence of global variables. In the case that the function definition is local to a function, is using named functions still leaky?

Comment: In javascript, newly declared variabled are "hoisted" to the top of the namespace. So your example is the same as doing `var mycallback = function() {...}`

Comment: Edit: My bad, your example is fine, since it's an IIFE.

Comment: The wrapper is an IIFE, but there's a named function within it.

Comment: What if the wrapper is named but immediately executed? Like `(function myWrapper() { function myCallback() { alert('callbacked'); } doSomething(myCallback); })();`

Comment: @Ygg myWrapper is in the "global" scope, it will leak. No different from `function myWrapper() {...}; myWrapper();`

Comment: Logically, it would make sense for the named callback to be in memory only as long as the object it's inside is in memory. How would it leak out into the global scope?

Comment: @abject_error: In Ygg's example, `myWrapper` is not a function definition, but a named function expression. It does not create a binding outside of the function unless you're using IE's buggy implementation of named function expressions.

Comment: My comment was in response to @icktoofay's example. Ygg's function is in global scope and will continue to stay in memory.

Comment: @tldr Are you referencing Ygg's comment? If so, scope is defined by the nearest parent "function" not the nearest pair of braces. There is a new keyword in upcoming versions of JS called "let" to allow you to name variables inside braces without causing them to leak.

Comment: haha, I wanted to clarify, but you beat me to the punch!

Comment: in icktoofey's example, since the named callback is within the scope of the self-executing function, it will be eligible for gc as soon as the self-executing function finishes executing. Am I correct?

Comment: sorry for so many questions, I'm just learning JS and Node and want to make sure I have a solid understanding of the fundamentals!

Comment: Yes. As I corrected myself a while back, IIFEs are perfectly fine when the outer function is anonymous.

Comment: I edited your answer to be [more] explicit that it only applies when the function has been added to the global scope, since that's basically what the sticking point was.

Comment: since coffeescript always wraps code in an anonymous function, is it safe to use named callbacks by default?

Comment: Yes, as long as you don't compile them with `--bare` which removes the wrapper.

Comment: great, another reason to love CS. Thanks a lot, appreciate your patience!

Comment: @tldr: Yes, that'll be okay, although because of the way CoffeeScript defines functions, you have to put all the callbacks before the code that uses the callback, e.g., `callbackA = -> doB callbackB` `callbackB = -> alert 'done'` `doA callbackA` rather than in JavaScript where the function definitions are hoisted so you could have a more linear progression: `doA(callbackA); function callbackA() { doB(callbackB); } function callbackB() { alert('done'); }` If you're doing lots of asynchronous things, you may want to look into control flow libraries like [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Comment: in fact it seems the expression in my comment indeed does not declare a function, as icktoofay said; check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fmvFp/ and this blog post https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

Comment: @icktoofay, why do i have to put callback definitions before they are called, in coffeescript? The variables are declared at the top of the function, so it shouldn't make a difference, should it?

Comment: I mean, if both the callback definition and the caller are in the same function, they should both have access to the same variables, shouldn't they?

Comment: @tldr: They have access to the same variables, yes, but if you have code like `doA callbackA` `callbackA = -> doB callbackB` `callbackB = -> alert 'done'` then by the time you get to call `doA`, `callbackA` has not yet been assigned. In JavaScript, functions definitions are hoisted. CoffeeScript does not have function definitions; it only has variables and function expressions. Variable declarations, like function definitions, are hoisted, but their initializers are not, so you'll end up calling `doA` with an `undefined` callback if the `callbackA = ->` part is after `doA callbackA`.